# Connect Azure Data Factory to SAP BW

Tags: azure-data-factory, sap-bw

I have an SSIS package that successfully uses the Microsoft SAP BW connector. The SAP Administrator has set up his side so that it uses a process chain and ProgramId as connection criteria.  I start my SSIS package and it runs in "Wait" mode until the SAP job executes.  This all works great.  I now need to replicate this using the Azure data factory's SAP BW connector but the Azure connector does not have the same look and feel so I am attempting to edit the code in the Connections tab for the SAPBW connection to include the Wait mode etc.

The SAP BW connection to the SAP BW system successfully passes the "Test Connection" in the Data Factory.

In the SSIS SAP BW connector the advanced properties display these values which I am trying to replicate (hope this image works):

[image link is broken] [image: SSIS SapBW]

So I added the "Custom Properties" to the code in the Connections -> linked Services->SapBw

```
    {
"name": "SapBw",
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
"properties": {
    "type": "SapBw",
    "typeProperties": {
        "server": "sapdb.compnme.local",
        "systemNumber": "00",
        "clientId": "400",
        "userName": "myUser",
        "encryptedCredential": "abc123"
    },
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "ARuntime",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    }
},
        "Custom Properties":{
        "DbTableName":"/BIC/OHCSST_OHD",
        "DestinationName":"CSST_OHD",
        "ExecutionMode":"W",
        "GatewayHost":"sapdb.compnme.local",
        "GatewayService":"sapgw00",
        "ProcessChain":"Z_CS_STAT_OHD",
        "ProgramId":"ProgId_P23",
        "Timeout":"1200"

    }
```

}

Unfortunately, when I click "Finish" the connection is successfully published but when I go to view the code my Custom Properties have disappeared.

Is there a different process to connect to SAP Open Hub with the Azure data factory?

(There does not appear to be anything on the MS website to guide me)

Answer (score 0):

Your image attachment could not display correctly. Based upon what I comprehend, I wonder if you confused ADF SSIS-IR and ADF Self-hosted IR.

Because you leveraged the BW connector in SSIS, apparently you were using the SSIS package and deployed it to ADF SSIS-IR stack. This IR has nothing to do with the Self-hosted IR which is required by ADF Copy activity from SAP BW. You mentioned you defined custom properties in the linked services, but the context of linked services is for the ADF native BW MDX connection interface. No matter what you define in the ADF linked services, it would not affect SSIS IR. Also, you may need to realize that ADF native BW interface is for MDX access only to query BW InfoCube and BEx QueryCube data. There is nothing to do with Open Hub.

Tactically, you should apply the custom properties to your BW connection in SSIS package, but I have a feeling that you may not know deeply the pros and cons of SSIS BW connector, ADF BW connector, Open Hub, and MDX. From real project experience, there are major robustness issues with the SSIS BW connector's integration with Open Hub and Process Chain. The DTP jobs inside the process chain could fail frequently, and the "reset" of DTP jobs is a frustrating experience. I suggest you describe your requirement before spending too much energy solving a connection property issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did some work with a Microsoft person - the process we wanted was to use an OpenHub connection in the Data Factory. This link to the Microsoft Azure Data Factory forum has a document that talks about how to achieve this. 
[DataFactory Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/dd6a8974-bcb1-4890-bd83-15eedace06f7/sap-bw-no-table-in-connection-tab?forum=AzureDataFactory)

Unfortunately this process didn't work for me becasue our SAP Version is 4 when it should work with 7.3 13.